# Knockout custom binding update not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

I am trying to add a custom binder for hasFocus to work like this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hasfocus = {

//update the control when the view model changes
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    alert('update');
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(3);
        if (value
            && element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight
            && document.activeElement && document.activeElement != element) {
            element.focus();
            ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "focusin"); // For IE, which doesn't reliably fire "focus" or "blur" events synchronously
        }
    });
}
```

};

But it never comes into this function ever. I am following this example

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/tAGmp/

The thing is, my input field is not visible in the start. If I click some place then it gets visible. The input field looks like this

```
<input type="text"  data-bind="hasFocus: true" />
```

I was trying to make it work with hard code value true. If it works then I will change it to some observable. Any thoughts?

Comment: You are overriding the whole `hasFocus` binding, so you are removing the built in `init` function. Add your custom function as in the example: `ko.bindingHandlers.hasfocus.update = function (element, valueAccessor) { your code here"`

Answer (score 0):

I have update the fiddle here. As you can see in your console, it is fired initially and when a value is typed in.

http://jsfiddle.net/tAGmp/11/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hasfocus = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        console.log('update');
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (value
                && element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight
                && document.activeElement && document.activeElement != element)
            {
                element.focus();
                ko.utils.triggerEvent(element, "focusin"); // For IE, which doesn't reliably fire "focus" or "blur" events synchronously
            }
        },0);
    }
};
```

Hopes this helps.